# How can I grep for division operator in C code with regex?

Tags: c, regex, grep

In a bunch of C code, I'd like to find all occurences of divisions (for reviewing them if they are checking division by zero). Thus, I'm trying to build a regular expression that I can use for grep to find all `/`.

I build some cases, what should be matched and what should not, because it is e.g. an include, a comment etc.:

Lines that should match:

```
int i = 5/0; //and a comment in line
double d = 58 * 17 / 16 / (3 + 5)
```

Lines that should not match:

```
 #include <include/pathes.h> (might have whitespaces in front)
bla // double slash for comments
/* single slash with * in block comments*/
// slashes inside comments / should be ignored
 // slashes inside comments / should be ignored (with whitespaces in front)
```

Thanks to https://regex101.com/, I tried following regex: `(?<![\/\*])\/(?![\/\*])`. This covers at least all matches, but wrongly matches the slashes in the include-lines and also the slashes inside comments.

How can I improve the regex in a way, that slashes in includes and slashes in comments are ignored? (I know, there can also be slahes in multi line comments, that are not so easy to grep, but I have to start somewhere.)

Does anyone has a better solution than grepping for `/` to find out divisions in source code?

Comment: Your compiler can do this for you.

Comment: I don't see a good way to exclude matches in `#include` lines, but you could consider scanning the preprocessed source, which will not include any.  That will also help you find division operations that are produced by macros.  On the other hand, it will also produce matches against the included content.

Comment: You can use `| grep -v '#include'` to remove the include lines.

Comment: @dbush That sounds very interesting. I would appreciate it if you could explain this in more detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @meddle0106 gcc in particular will generate a warning on integer division by zero at compile time.

Comment: @dbush From what I've understood, this warning only occurs on clear things like my first match example. When the divisor is e.g. the return of another function, this cannot be statically analysed by the compiler.

Comment: @meddle0106 In which case grep definitely can't find that.  You're better off purchasing a static analysis tool.

Comment: @dbush You might be assuming that the strawman example given in the question, which happens to be a constant expression, is the real use case.

Comment: regex can't be used for this. You need a real parser

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is your compiler.

Your next best bet is to filter the source with perl and delete the comments and includes.

Given:

```
$ cat file
int i = 5/0; //and a comment in line
double d = 58 * 17 / 16 / (3 + 5) /* old single line comment */

double f=3/0; /* multiline comment
with / in it
end */

#include <include/pathes.h> (might have whitespaces in front)
bla // double slash for comments
/* single slash with /* in block comments*/
// slashes inside comments / should be ignored
// slashes inside comments / should be ignored (with whitespaces in front)
```

You can delete all comments and includes like so:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\///g; 
                s/^\s*#.*//mg; s/[\/]{2}.*//g;' file
```

prints:

```
int i = 5/0; 
double d = 58 * 17 / 16 / (3 + 5) 

double f=3/0; 

bla
```

Then do a simple `grep` on that:

```
perl -0777 -pE 's/\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\///g;
            s/^\s*#.*//mg; s/[\/]{2}.*//g;' file | grep '/'
```

Prints:

```
int i = 5/0; 
double d = 58 * 17 / 16 / (3 + 5) 

double f=3/0;
```

---

Or, if you want to do it all in `perl` and keep
`/* single line comments */` and `// comments` after the code:

```
perl -0777 -nE 's/(\/\*(?:\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/)/($1=~qr"\R") ? "" : $1/eg;
                s/^\s*#.*//mg;
                for $l (split /\R+/, $_) {
                    @parts=split /(?:\/\/)|(?:\/\*)/, $l;
                    say $l if $parts[0]=~/\//;
                }
' file
```

Prints:

```
int i = 5/0; //and a comment in line
double d = 58 * 17 / 16 / (3 + 5) /* old single line comment */
double f=3/0;
```

### Limitations

This is strictly line oriented (other than the multiline comment removal.) There are legit C statements that span multiple lines. This will only find the single line that has `/` on it that is not inside a comment. To work with C statements vs a line of C that may or may not be complete you need a parser of C code (such as your compiler.)